# Array Merge - but 3 uncertain arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I want to display debug information on my page.

```
$merge_debug = array_merge($snow, $snowadvanced, $snowtechnical);
print_r($merge_debug);
```

However, the arrays `$snow`, `$snowadvanced` and `$snowtechnical` don't exist if a user did not save the settings.

I need to check if the mentioned above arrays exist or not, and if they exist, `print_r` them after merging them.

What's the best way to do this without having messy coding? I've already tried `foreach` looping them, but that didn't work out. Help would be much appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use isset to check

```
function check($var)
{
  return isset($var) ? $var : []; 
}
$merge_debug = array_merge(check($snow), check($snowadvanced), check($snowtechnical));
print_r($merge_debug);
```

Comment: Some might work and some might not, so what if `$snow` works and `$snowtechnical` is empty?

Comment: Is not when all the array defined, I get your means.